# Automatic background scan if user edit column?

Tags: javascript, php, database

Quite new to all this stuff so my apologies if this question is obvious.

So my problem is: If the user enter a valid ***item ID***, the script will scan the ***item ID*** and return the ***Shelf ID*** of that ***item ID***. I want this to be automatic so my user can scan multiple ***item ID***'s at the same time. The ***Shelf ID*** should be displayed at the red line in the picture below.

**Note:** I don't want to use the Check Status/Shelf button that I have right now, I want it to be automatic like onEdit or something similar.

Is this possible to accomplish with JavaScript?
[image: like this]

Comment: What you need is Ajax. Look at jQuery $.ajax, it'll get you started - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: How should JavaScript knows which Shelf ID is with which Item ID ? Do you store these links in any database ? If yes, don't forget to mention it.

Comment: Start out with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 And then Google for `PHP ajax` there a zillion tutorials and just as many stackoverflow questions. As written this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: @Zeratops Yeah I forgot to mention that... Every item ID and Shelf ID are stored in a Database.

Comment: Ok so it definitively change the answer, because when we talk about checking value from a database dynamically, we think about AJAX as my collegues mentioned it. And yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks all! I will take a look at AJAX today.

Comment: @Snoken I've written a quick example for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with jQuery and Ajax. Firstly create a PHP file to do the lookup and return the shelf ID for you.

```
<?php
$itemId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'itemId', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); // Make sure than an integer has been passed.
$query = "SELECT shelfId from myTable WHERE itemId = $itemId";
//... run query
// store shelfId in $shelfId
echo json_encode(array('itemId' => $itemId, 'shelfId' => $shelfId));
```

Next we need to set up the jQuery Ajax call. Give all your inputs a class that you can attach an event to. I'll use a class of `myClass` for now.

```
$('.myClass').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/file/above.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { itemId: $(this).val() };
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert("Item: "+response.itemId+", Shelf: "+response.shelfId);
    });
});
```